# Is it possible to calculate a C-style `enum` value using a macro?

Tags: enums, macros, rust

I have a huge list of four letter identifiers. I want an enum constant for each of them. The value of the constant should be the ASCII identifier as `u32`.

```
enum E {
    Elem = my_macro!(Elem),
}
```

Since the macro will simply be replaced by the resulting AST the compiler will see a non constant expression and raise an error.

Is this possible, or do I have to generate write the constants out explicitly?

Comment: Perhaps consider macros 1.1 or using the build.rs script (with handlebars templating) to do codegen?

Comment: @user25064 Could you expand on how you think Macros 1.1 would help here? The answer below already mentions a build script.

Comment: since you have the enum elements as a string is it possible to iterate over chars with macros 1.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of, yes, but remember that macros really only allow you to remove drudgery, not really add new features.

Start by writing the code you want **without macros**. This lets you see what is possible. For example, my exploring went like this:

```
#[repr(u32)]
enum Foo {
    Start = (1 << 24 | 2 << 16 | 3 << 8 | 4) as u32,
    Start2 = ((b'1' as u32) << 24 | 2 << 16 | 3 << 8 | 4) as u32,
    // the index operation on const values is unstable
    //Start3 = ((b"1"[0] as u32) << 24 | 2 << 16 | 3 << 8 | 4) as u32,
}
```

Sadly, we cannot use the last form as indexing into a constant isn't a constant expression (yet). As far as I can tell, the best we can do is `Start2`. Next, repeat the pattern a few times to see where the redundancy occurs:

```
#[repr(u32)]
enum Foo {
    Start = ((b'S' as u32) << 24 | (b'T' as u32) << 16 | (b'R' as u32) << 8 | (b'T' as u32)) as u32,
    End   = ((b' ' as u32) << 24 | (b'E' as u32) << 16 | (b'N' as u32) << 8 | (b'D' as u32)) as u32,
}
```

Now you are primed to create a macro:

```
macro_rules! tagged_ascii_headers {
    (enum $name:ident {
        $($var:ident = $v1:expr, $v2:expr, $v3:expr, $v4:expr,)*
    }) => {
        #[repr(u32)]
        enum $name {
            $($var = (($v1 as u32) << 24 | ($v2 as u32) << 16 | ($v3 as u32) << 8 | $v4 as u32),)*
        }
    }
}

tagged_ascii_headers! {
    enum Foo {
        Start = b'S', b'T', b'R', b'T',
        End   = b' ', b'E', b'N', b'D',
    }
}
```

Then you can play with the macro syntax to find something that looks nice. I got down to

```
macro_rules! tagged_ascii_headers {
    (enum $name:ident {
        $($var:ident = $v1:tt $v2:tt $v3:tt $v4:tt,)*
    }) => {
        #[repr(u32)]
        enum $name {
            $($var = (($v1 as u32) << 24 | ($v2 as u32) << 16 | ($v3 as u32) << 8 | $v4 as u32),)*
        }
    }
}

tagged_ascii_headers! {
    enum Foo {
        Start = 'S' 'T' 'R' 'T',
        End   = ' ' 'E' 'N' 'D',
    }
}
```

This is a bit nicer, but ultimately you might need more constant evaluation to be available. **If** arrays could be indexed, you could evolve to something like

```
tagged_ascii_headers! {
    enum Foo {
        Start = b"STRT",
        End   = b" END",
    }
}
```

---

> Since the macro will simply be replaced by the resulting AST

This is true

> the compiler will see a non constant expression

This is half-true. For example, this compiles just fine:

```
macro_rules! foo {
    () => { 42 }
}

enum Foo {
    Start = foo!(),
}
```

So really, the *macro* is irrelevant to the const-ness, it's all about what the macro *expands to*.

---

You could also move to a build script:

```
const THINGS: &'static [(&'static str, &'static [u8; 4])] = &[
    ("Start", b"STRT"),
    ("End",   b" END"),
];

fn main() {
    println!("#[repr(u32)]");
    println!("enum Foo {{");
    for &(name, code) in THINGS {
        let code = (code[0] as u32) << 24 | 
                   (code[1] as u32) << 16 |
                   (code[2] as u32) << 8  |
                    code[3] as u32;
        println!("    {} = {},", name, code);
    }
    println!("}}");
}
```

You'd want to write that to a file instead of standard output, then include the generated file from the production code. A build script would also allow you to have some external file that defines all the names / codes, if that was valuable.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer. A buildscript seems to be the cleanest solution. Although I'd hoped to be able to solve this in language.

Comment: @BlankChisui *to solve this in language* — a build script **is** part of the language. You are still writing Rust code, and it's a first-class aspect of Cargo. Plenty of projects use build scripts.